# Alterar layout de um radioButtonList / checkBoxList WebForms para que fique compatível com Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Como é sabido, o formato padrão de layout de um radiobutton ou checkbox em controles de lista no Asp.Net WebForms
é sempre algo como

```
 <label></label><input>
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira decente de alterar o layout de exibição para torná-lo compatível com as classes de formulário do Bootstrap.

Comment: Qual versão do bootstrap você pretende usar?

Comment: É algo legado? Se for algo novo recomendo usar MVC, você tem mais liberdade na apresentação.

Comment: É legado sim, cara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Asp.Net WebForms os controles  geram um output em html controlado pelo proprio Asp.Net, da seguinte forma:

a tag asp.net:

```html
<asp:CheckBoxList id="check1" AutoPostBack="True" TextAlign="Right" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Check" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Gera um output em html de:

```html
<table id="check1">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="check1_0" type="checkbox" name="check1$0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;check1$0\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" value="Item 1" /><label for="check1_0">Item 1</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="check1_1" type="checkbox" name="check1$1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;check1$1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" value="Item 2" /><label for="check1_1">Item 2</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Em todo controle WebControl é possível definir um Css através da propriedade CssClass="string", por exemplo:

```html
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="minhaClassCSS" />
```

output:

```html
<input type=text class="minhaClassCSS" style="ForeColor:red">
```

Infelizmente não é fácil saber como cada controle WebControl será gerado em HTML, isto é, o WebForms facilita a vida do programador na contrução do layout porem tira dele o poder de manipula-lo. Essa é uma grande vantagem do asp.net MVC o poder volta a mão do programador porem agora é sua responsabilidade escrever um HTML bem feito.

No caso de utilizar o Twitter-Bootstrap com o WebForms não existe uma maneira fácil, será necessário criar as class no seu css semelhante a aquele que você deseja utilizar do Bootstrap e torcer para que o output dos seus controles sejam compatíveis.

Fonte: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Corrigi criando um css adapter e classes auxiliares pra resolver esses layouts quebrados. Pelo visto é a única solução mais simples mesmo. Outra alternatica seria criar userControls customizados, mas já seria demais pra pouco benefício.

Answer (score 0):

Só seguir a recomendação do próprio site do Bootstrap, adicionando as classes em cada Tag. Para Forms, o link é o seguinte:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Usarei a versão 3.1.1 como exemplo (versão mais atual quando esta resposta foi escrita).

Normalmente usa-se o seguinte padrão:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exemplo">Exemplo</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exemplo" placeholder="Exemplo">
</div>
```

Veja a seção `CheckBoxes and Radios`. Tem um exemplo mais ou menos assim:

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
  </label>
</div>
```

Como não sei como é seu form, o ideal é ler os exemplos e ir mudando as `div`s de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Comment: Não foi isso que eu perguntei, cara.

Comment: Bom, então elabore melhor sua pergunta, porque não está claro.